# Adicionar referencia no Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

Eu usava o Visual Studio 2017, e tinha uma área para adicionar referencia. Quando mudei para o Visual Studio 2019, notei que o botão mudou de nome.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu tento adicionar uma referencia não funciona,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a caixa não permanece marcada e aparece um novo campo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É um aplicativo .Net Framework ou .Net Core? Normalmente você vai em "assemblies" e não na pesquisa. Para aplicativos .Net Core você tem que instalar o nuget correspondente. Me lembro que antes havia System.Windows.Forms no nuget Manager, mas parece que foi removido. De qualquer maneira encontrei essa pergunta que talvez possa te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460253/how-to-use-system-windows-forms-in-net-core-class-library

Comment: Se for um aplicativo .Net Framework (e seu visual studio estiver bem atualizado) há uma maneira mais prática: escreva Form f1 = new Form(); no seu código, coloque o cursor em cima da definição Form ( que ficará sublinhada de vermelho) e pressione Ctr+. (control ponto). Aparecerá um menu, selecione "using System.Windows.Forms". Ele adicionará a referência e a instrução using automaticamente. O visual studio utiliza algum algorítmo de correspondência e as vezes até encontra qual pacote deve ser instalado, mas nem sempre funciona, e isso só funciona nas versões mais recentes.